# foreign key has not been updated along with primary key?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I HAVE TWO TABLES.

```
customer_details(c_id,c_name,c_phone) primary_key(c_id) ENGINE:innoDB AUTO  INCREMENT

service_initiation(c_id2,si_id,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) primary_key(si_id) AUTO INCREMENT and  ENGINE:innoDB foreign_key(c_id2) references customer_details(c_id) on delete cascade and on update cascade
```

However i use i insert data through a html page and use php code to insert values into database using phpmyadmin.

BUT am getting an error while inserting values into the table.

ERROR IS:

> error inserting values to the table: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`workshop_service`.`service_initiation`, CONSTRAINT `service_initiation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`c_id2`) REFERENCES `customer_details` (`c_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE).

BELOW IS MY PHP CODE:

```
$value1=mysql_insert_id();
$value2=$_POST['si_1'];
$value3=$_POST['si_2'];
$value4=$_POST['si_3'];
$value5=$_POST['si_4'];
$value6=$_POST['si_5'];


$query="insert into service_initiation(c_id2,si_id,si_1,si_2,si_3,si_4,si_5) values ('$value1','','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6')";
 mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: $value1 is likely to not correspond to any customer_details.c_id record.

Comment: but there exists a value in customer_details.c_id feild.but it has not been updated to foreign key "service_initiation.c_id2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not updating any data in customer_details, so the foreign key shouldn't be updated. So, your title is misleading.
2. When you insert data into child table and get this error, it means, that the value, that you try to insert into foreign key field is missing in the parent table.

Comment: i mean inserting a value in the primary key of customer_details table should be updated with foreign key of service_initiation table.

Comment: @AngryBuddha Show the data you have in customer_details table in your question